# Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported (6275)

Tags: visual-studio, openzeppelin

I need help with the following error while learning contracts. The error is in the title. I am using a Macbook and VS Code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYWqV.png)

The code is not compiling and I need help trying to figure out how to get the code to run